# Independence in counting problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been re-working some counting problems that I did in college (a long time ago in a galaxy far far away) and I just had an insight that I would like verification on.

Consider the following two problems:

> How many meals can be formed from 3 appetizers 2 mains and 3 desserts?

Everyone learns that this is simply,
$$3*2*3$$
and that this resulting set is **unordered**, meaning that $$\{Salad,Chicken,Pie\} = \{Pie,Chicken,Salad\} $$
People call this the fundamental counting rule sometimes.

Okay, now on the opposite end we have complete dependence,

> How many ways can a president and vice president be chosen from a group of 5 people?

Everyone's intuition here is again
$$5*4$$
which looks an awful lot like the above, except our result is **ordered**.
How can that be since in both cases we are just taking the product over all possibilities?

This confused me for a long time until I realized the crucial difference is *independence*. The reason the top is unordered is because appetizer is independent of main course which is independent of dessert, whereas the reason the bottom is ordered is because picking a vice president is not independent of picking a president because the sample space decreases by $1$

Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is correct. You can refer to [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) to understand why the first one order doesn't matter but the second one does.

> **Rule of product.** If there are $a$ ways of doing action $A$ and $b$ ways of doing action $B$ thing, then there are $ab$ ways of performing both actions.

For the first one, three actions are: choosing appetisers, choosing mains and choosing deserts. The combination of three actions will be choosing an appetiser, a main and a desert in which order doesn't matter.

For the second one, two actions are: choosing the first one out of $5$ people to be present and choosing one from the rest $4$ people to be vice president. With these actions, we can see that the order matters, where first person we choose must be president. Hence, we have $(A,B) \ne (B,A)$ since with $(A,B)$ then $A$ is the president, but with $(B,A)$ then $B$ is the president.

Answer (score 0):

> and that this resulting set is **unordered**, meaning that

Actually, it is *ordered*: appetiser, main, then dessert.

Consider if: pie were both main and dessert, chicken both main and appetiser, and pancake both appetiser and dessert, then (pancake, chicken, pie) and (chicken, pie, pancake) would be different meals.

Comment: That is not true, consider a simpler example. Two drinks and two main courses. Define them as
$B_1,B_2,D_1,D_2$
then we have 
$(B_1,D_1),(B_2,D_1),(B_1,D_2),(B_2,D_2)=2*2=4$
If it were ordered then we would need to count $(D_1,B_1)$ as a separate meal yielding a larger answer then given by the product rule

Comment: Just consider the indices.  You have $(1,1), (2,1), (1,2), (2,2)$

Comment: you can't just consider the indices because there are two elements mapped to (1,1)...both (D1,B1) and (B1,D1)

Comment: You can consider the indices, because the position of the index maps to the category.

Comment: I think If you read the accepted answer you will get some iintuition as to why they are different

Comment: The position of the index maps to the category uniquely only of it is unordered, otherwise the same index would have to map to both D and B

Comment: They are not different.  In both cases you are making selections from a set number of options for different categories.  It's just that in the second case, what the options for the second category *are* changes according to what was selected for the first category,

Comment: $(1,1)$ *does* map to $B_1, D_1$.

Comment: But if order mattered then it would also map to D1,B1

Comment: In English, ordering a drink then a meal would count and ordering a meal then a drink would count...we don't do that here, we only count ordering a drink then a meal

Comment: Yes, order matters *because* $(1,2)$ maps to $B_1, D_2$ - we only count ordering a drink then a meal.

Comment: That's not the definition of ordered versus unordered in counting. Ordered means $$(D_1,B_1) \neq (B_1,D_1)$$

Comment: Ah I see what's wrong , we have inverted definitions of ordered

Comment: In the same way, $President_{Dave}. VicePresident_{John}$ is distinct from $President_{John}, VicePresident_{Dave}$, and if you only consider the index. $(Dave, John)$ and $(John, Dave)$ are distinct because the first position of the index maps to the category of President.

Comment: Only counting drink then meal is considered unordered

Comment: Right in the president example we count index flips and therefore it is ordered. In the fast food we only count I,j so it is unordered

Comment: Only counting President then Vice President is consider ....?

Comment: So in president example (Dave,John) != (John,Dave) and in the fast food (Coke,burger)=(burger,coke) so they are different

Comment: I know it is confusing because we say pick a drink then a burger but that is actually unordered because we are implicitly ignoring the possibility of picking a burger then a drink

Comment: No, the only difference is that Burger is not selectable as a drink and Coke cannot be selected as a meal.  But if they could....

Comment: Yeah and because we can't do that this problem is by definition unorderd

Comment: Both cases are ordered by category.

Comment: Read this http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.mcdonalds.html

Comment: It's not just my definition it's the accepted definiton of ordered

Comment: That's talking about the order in which the categories may be arranged, not in which the selections are made into the categories.  Note you can do the same with categories "President" and "Vice President".

Comment: And that is the definition or ordered in counting...if you were asked on a test if that is ordered or unordered, you would circle unordered, or get a point off :) Anyway, thanks for chatting about this.

Answer (score -1):

The  [*product rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) for counting says that if a task consists of three steps, there are $n_1$ ways to do the first step of the task, there are $n_2$ ways to do the second step regardless of which choice was made in the first step, and there are $n_3$ ways to do the third step regardless of which choices were made in the first two steps, then the number of ways to complete the task is the product $n_1 n_2 n_3$.

This formula is applicable to both your examples.  There is some kind of independence here (and therefore some kind of independence in both your examples) because the number of ways $n_2$ to do the second step is independent of which choice was made in the first step, and similarly for $n_3$.

Comment: There is explicit dependence in the second example, you cannot choose John for Vice-President if you chose him for president

Comment: The independence is in the _number of ways_ to choose the vice-president: it is 4 regardless of who was chosen for the president.

Comment: that is not what is relevant here. In the first example, your choice of chocolate cake doesn't impact your choice of burger because they are independent, in the second example your choice of president does impact your choice of vice president because you can't choose the person named president

Comment: Think about it some more...

Comment: think about whether the items at each step depend on the items previously chosen

Comment: The problem you stated is a counting problem, and you want to count the number of objects in some collection.  In your first collection, you can restrict each 3-tuple $(a,b,c)$ to be such that $a$ is an appetizer, $b$ a main menu item and $c$ a dessert. You can impose that order if you wish. The size of your collection is $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$. Similarly, the size of your second collection of 2-tuples is $5 \cdot 4$.

Comment: Yes, but the first set the elements are selected independently, i.e. P(Coke | Burger) =  Coke where as in the second set they are not P(John | Andrew) != P(John)

Comment: look at https://www.thatquiz.org/tq/previewtest?T/B/K/Q/35371261394273 problem 13

Comment: `13. choosing a president, vice president, secretary, and treasurer for Student Council, assuming that a person can hold only one office

A) dependent event
B) independent event`

Comment: Answer key says A, sorry I am so ruthless :)

Comment: Your question is not about dependent versus independent events, but about an explanation for why you can take the product in both examples even though in one case order matters and in another case it doesn't.  In both cases the product rule applies because the number of ways to do the second step is independent of which choice was made in the first step. The choice made in the second step is of course dependent on the choice made in the first step, but the number of ways to make the choice in the second step is independent of the choice made in the first step.

Comment: Imagine drawing out a tree that grows to the right. The root has 5 branches going out (for 5 choices you could make for the President), and at the endpoint of each of these 5 branches, you draw 4 branches for the possible choices in the second step. The number of leaves in this tree is $5 \cdot 4$. One could contrive of other kinds of (more complicated) problems where the number of branches in the second step would be different for different choices in the first step, in which case the product rule wouldn't apply.

Comment: Ah we are both wrong. The product rule does apply in both situations because it is about the number of ways of doing something (as you mentioned), but the product rule does not imply independence in the generating process, or is that why you said some kind of independence?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, the product rule assumes a certain independence (or regularity, if you want to call it that) in the procedure: the number of branches coming out of a vertex in each stage of the tree is the same for all the vertices in that stage.

Comment: But doesn't the independence in the data generating process of example A mean that the resulting set is unordered. However, in example B because of the dependence on people (not number of people) imply that the set is ordered.

Comment: I prefer to think of the first example also as being ordered - the collection consists of a set of 3-tuples $(a,b,c)$ as I mentioned above. Tuples are ordered sets. Whichever works for you is fine, but remember the question is a counting problem, which means it is asking to count the number of objects in some collection. How you define the collection (a collection of unordered sets or a collection of ordered 3-tuples) is up to you.

Comment: But if you do it correctly, then there will be a bijective correspondence between your collection and the collection described in the problem, so that the size of your collection is equal to the size of the collection described in the problem, and so counting the size of your collection would give the correct answer.

Comment: So I guess this is mostly a problem of English. It is not `ordered` in the sense that order matters (meaning you count the transpose), but it is generated in an ordered way. Why don't people teach to this level of subtlety

Comment: Actually you are incorrect , define $X_t$ To be the number of ways to choose people for position $t$ . We can express $X_t$ as $X_{t-1} -1$. Therefore the random variables are dependent. However in the first problem there is no functional form to represent $X_t$ as a function of $x_{t-1}$

Comment: Therefore the product rule does not apply for the second problem.